# What is the Retail (ie. Non-Discounted) Pricing for Salesforce Communities?

Tags: community, portal, pricing

As of September 2013, there are two types of Salesforce Communities.

- Customer Communities
- Partner Communities

Pricing for these is a complete mystery. The only thing I've been able to find out, courtesy of this [May 2, 2013 press release](http://www.salesforce.com/company/news-press/press-releases/2013/05/130502.jsp), is that "pricing for Salesforce Communities will start at $500 month".

We all know that there's a lot more to it than that. What we don't know, and what I can't find *anywhere*, is **how much more**.

Here are some of my specific questions.

- Are Communities licensed solely on a per-user basis, or does the "block pricing" model that was introduced for Authenticated Sites / High-Volume Portal Users live on in some fashion?
- What are the typical "tiers" for licensed Communities users? For example, 1-1000, 1001-5000, 5001-15000, etc.
- What is the retail "sticker price" of each "tier"?  Every company is going to negotiate something different with Salesforce, but there must be a baseline, right?

Finally, here's a related question: Why is this information not generally available?

Salesforce always struck me as being relatively transparent with the majority of its pricing, at least providing retail prices for most standard platform features.  Why are portals (and now Communities) such a black hole?

Heck, are we even *allowed* to be asking these questions?  ;-)

Comment: You can ask, just don't expect an answer. Salesforce pricing matrices are closely guarded secrets. I think they do this to avoid customers playing the numbers to come up with the most favorably discounted set of features (like those extreme couponers you see on television).

Answer (score 2):

It's because it's kinda complicated and it may move around as they gauge customer response.

For partner communities, there is a named user model that pretty much follows the older partner portal pricing.  But they also have a logins/month option (something you used to only see on customer portal) for orgs with larger numbers of infrequent partners.  And there are blocks/tiers on both depending on how many you need.

They'll give you the matrix on request...it's just not a quick answer like "sales cloud is $x/mo/user" and it makes sense to explain your needs.

I haven't looked at customer community yet so I can't speak for that.

Comment: Thanks for the note about asking for the matrix.  I'll give that a shot!