# Customer Community Login and Customer Community Profile License

Tags: customer-community

What is the difference between a “*Customer Community Login*” license, and a “*Customer Community*” license?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21949/what-is-the-difference-between-a-customer-community-login-license-and-a-cust

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the reference above, [What is the Retail (ie. Non-Discounted) Pricing for Salesforce Communities?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16749/what-is-the-retail-ie-non-discounted-pricing-for-salesforce-communities) also discusses the difference between per-user licenses (e.g. customer community license) and per-login licenses for a larger community of infrequent users (e.g. customer community login licenses).